# Access CiviCRM event fees via Drupal Views

Tags: views, civicrm

I'm trying to access the Regular Fees data inside of Drupal Views 3. I can see the Fee Label but can't see how I pull in Regular Fees? I've looked at Price sets and setting up a relationship but this seems overly complex for whats required. Wondering if anyone has attempted this/had any joy? Using Drupal 7.42 and CiviCRM 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using Views Field View following: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-field-view/

You'll need to create the context on Price Set ID in **Price Fields**, not Price Set.

I don't think this is an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module, and its sub module CiviCRM Entity Views Extras...

CiviCRM Events, Contributions, Participants, ParticipantPayment, LineItems, PriceSet, PriceField, PriceFieldValues, FinancialTrxn, and other necessary entities are exposed, and some of the relationship handlers are provided by the CiviCRM Entity Views Extras modules, but a few more may need to be added depending on your use case.

But it can be done, lots of the heavy lifting has been done already.